# CSS styled social media buttons not lining up on specific posts

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Standard Theme for a Wordpress blog, and on "image" posts like those here: http://www.justinmclachlan.com/topics/photos/ , the social media buttons on the bottom all line up except for the last one, which is an arrow that reveals a few more choices.

I have searched and searched the CSS, and I can't see a reason that it's not lining up. It works fine on other kinds of posts, just not image posts for some reason.

I did change some of the CSS to move the buttons to line up on the right and take out a border, but this is all I did:

```
div.sharedaddy .sd-content {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
}

div.sharedaddy div.sd-block {
    border:none;
    padding:12px 0 0;
}
```

Can't see how that's messing anything up... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the 'no-text' class onto the 'a' tag I think that fixes it for you.